# scrom completion status by latest attempt

Tags: mysql, sql, moodle

I am trying to get the SCORM completion report with the latest/last attempt made by user. But with the code below I am getting all the attempts made by user like attempts 1,2... for example the latest/last attempt by a user is 2 then I want only that attempt number 2 in output but here I am getting both 1 and 2 attempts as completed/incompleted. Any SQL QUERY would be helpful.

#Here is my code

```
SELECT u.firstname AS First, u.lastname AS Last, c.fullname AS Course, sc.name as scromname, st.attempt AS Attempt, st.value AS Status,
FROM_UNIXTIME(st.timemodified,"%m-%d-%Y") AS Date 
FROM mdl_scorm_scoes_track AS st 
JOIN mdl_user AS u ON st.userid=u.id
JOIN mdl_scorm AS sc ON sc.id=st.scormid
JOIN mdl_course AS c ON c.id=sc.course
WHERE st.element='cmi.core.lesson_status'
UNION
SELECT user2.firstname AS First, user2.lastname AS Last, c.fullname AS Course, sc.name as scromname, "-" AS Attempt, "not_started" AS Status, "-" AS Date
FROM mdl_user_enrolments AS ue
JOIN mdl_enrol AS e ON e.id = ue.enrolid
JOIN mdl_course AS c ON c.id = e.courseid
JOIN mdl_user AS user2 ON user2 .id = ue.userid
JOIN mdl_scorm AS sc ON sc.course=c.id
left Join mdl_scorm_scoes_track AS st on st.scormid=sc.id AND st.userid=user2.id
WHERE  st.timemodified IS NULL
ORDER BY  Course, Last, First, Attempt
```

Comment: 'Any SQL QUERY would be helpful.' - so would publishing table definitions,, sample data and desired outcome as text. BTW SCROM is not something I guess most of us have encountered. and I think it's spelled SCORM anyway..

Answer (score 0):

I do not know much about your schema, but I will nevertheless describe the idea. Hopefully you will be able to implement this idea for your schema, but, if not, then you will need to provide more information.

Basically, let's suppose that there is a tries table, like this:

**tries(id, dt, user_id, ...someothercolumns...)**

Now, let's do a `left join` that will exclude all the non-latest elements, like this:

```
select tries1.dt, tries1.user_id, ...
from tries tries1
lef join tries tries2
on tries1.user_id = tries2.user_id and tries1.dt < tries2.dt
where tries2.id is null;
```

Explanation:

- we are searching for any records from `tries1`
- for which there does not exist any `tries2` record that

  - shares the user
  - is newer than tries1